# Remove Custom Taxonomy Slug only without removing Custom post type slug in permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, terms, slug

I have a problem currently that is related to permalinks. I have a custom Post type "**workshop**" and two taxonomies named "**manufacturer**" and "**models**". What i want to get and tried is this URL pattern.

**Current permalinks for accessing posts under this  post type**

```
www.domain.com/workshop/[manufacturer name]/[models]/post name
e.g www.domain.com/workshop/Rover/R1/postname
```

And for accessing taxonomies terms

For manufacturer

```
www.domain.com/manufacturer/[term name]
```

What i want to get is this URL for accessing **Taxonomy terms**

```
www.domain.com/[custom postype slug]/[term name]/
www.domain.com/workshop/rover/
```

Means to add only Custom post type slug as a base and to remove Taxonomy Base slug from URL,s

I have tried some plugins e.g **Remove custom taxonomy base slug** but what they did is this URL pattern ( they remove both custom post type and taxonomy slug from URL )

```
www.domain.com/[term name]/
www.domain.com/rover/
```

Can its possible to do this with rewrite structure so  i can only remove taxonomy slug not custom post type slug from URL,s ?

Comment: Is this somehow specific how AdvancedCustomFields sets it up? If so, please consult their support forums.

Comment: @kaiser Its not related to any custom field or plugin. Its related to Custom taxonomies and terms and their permalinks. Thanks